# how to reposition an icon inside a Flex button on any x,y cordinates 

Tags: apache-flex, button, icons

how to reposition an icon inside a button on any x,y cordinates . i know how to use labelplacement etc but still i dont get the full control over them. i m just wondering if there is a way to directly access and control the x,y position of an icon in a flex button

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the Button class and unfortunately the icon positioning code takes place in a private method, so it can't be overridden.

But you could create your own button by extending a Canvas and adding to it an Image and a Label. Then position the image wherever you want. Skin the control in CSS using whatever button skins you normally use ([YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/articles/yahoo-flex-skin.html) has some nice, open-source ones) and then just set buttonMode=true, tabEnabled=true (if necessary) and useHandCursor=true (if desired). Presto, you have your very own button, just the way you like it.